Implementing Supabase Typescript Types
I am trying to use Supabase typescript types in my Next.js project, but I get the error Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.
I am following this documentation. I have generated the types just fine, but I can't use them in my app.
When I try to use this code:
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/server";
import { Database } from "@/types/supabase";

export async function myFunction() {
  const supabase = createClient<Database>();
}

The <Database> gives me this error:
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.. If I take out <Database> I get no error, but I then lose my typesafety

Try this:
import { Database } from '@/types/supabase'
import { createServerClient, type CookieOptions } from '@supabase/ssr'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export const createClient = () => {
 => {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  return createServerClient<Database>(
    process.env.SUPABASE_URL!,
    {
      cookies: {
        get(name: string) {
          return cookieStore.get(name)?.value
        },
        set(name: string, value: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value, ...options })
          } catch (error) {
            // The `set` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
        remove(name: string, options: CookieOptions) {
          try {
            cookieStore.set({ name, value: '', ...options })
          } catch (error) {
            // The `delete` method was called from a Server Component.
            // This can be ignored if you have middleware refreshing
            // user sessions.
          }
        },
      },
    }
  )
}


Yup, this is it. The issue I was having was that I was trying to add <Database> when creating a client: const supabase = createClient(), however what I needed to do was add <Database> into the client.ts and server.ts utils/supabase/ when exporting the  createClient().
Thank you!
